# web.config error 500.19 </configuration> XML Error: mismatched tag

Tags: asp.net, xml, iis-7

I'm hosting my site on a commercial server IIS6 - i'm trying to move it to one of their IIS7 boxes. (code works fine on IIS6) I'm getting 500.19 error stating the web.config file is the error? (same file on both servers) I have the IIS7 box set to classic mode. Hosting company is no help! - when I view my config file I do see "XML Error : mismatched tag" but why? it;s the last line `</configuration>` and matches the 2nd line `<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">`

here is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">

<appSettings>
<add key="DefaultConnectionString" value="AccessMembershipProvider" />
<add key="EmailFrom" value="webmaster@domain.com"/>
<add key="EmailTo" value="xyz@hotmail.com"/>
<add key="BlindEmail" value="xyz@hotmail.com"/>
<add key="TechTrainingConn" value="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source=e:\App_Data\Tech_Training.mdb"/>
<add key="TechTraining" value="~/App_Data/Training.mdb" />
</appSettings>

<connectionStrings>
<add name="OdbcServices" connectionString="Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=e:\App_Data\Training.mdb;" />
<add name="OBDCConnectionString" connectionString="Dsn=MS Access Database;dbq=e:\App_Data\Tech_Training.mdb;defaultdir=e:\App_Data;driverid=25;fil=MS Access;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;uid=admin"
  providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
 <add name="TTSite" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=e:\App_Data\Tech_Training.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
<add name="accessConnectionString" connectionString="~/App_Data/Tech_Training.mdb" />
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="network" from="webmaster@domain.com">
    <network
      host="localhost"
      port="25"
      defaultCredentials="true"
    />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<compilation debug="true"/>
<authentication mode="Forms" />
<membership defaultProvider="AccessMembershipProvider" 
            userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
  <providers>
    <add name="AccessMembershipProvider"
          type="AccessMembershipProvider"
          enablePasswordReset="true" 
          enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
          connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=e:\App_Data\Tech_Training.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
    />
  </providers>

</membership>

<roleManager defaultProvider="OdbcRoleProvider"
              enabled="true"
              cacheRolesInCookie="true"
              cookieName=".ASPROLES"
              cookieTimeout="30"
              cookiePath="/"
              cookieRequireSSL="false"
              cookieSlidingExpiration="true"
              cookieProtection="All" >

  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="OdbcRoleProvider"
        type="Samples.AspNet.Roles.OdbcRoleProvider"
        connectionStringName="OdbcServices"
        applicationName="SampleApplication"
        writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
  </providers>

</roleManager>

</system.web>

<location path="XYZ">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Admin" />
      <allow roles="Chiefs" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web> 
</location>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue isn't the last line, you're missing the closing tag on the connectionstrings element.

Comment: Thanks, just realized that a few min ago, fixed it!